# Is there a way to convert geojson coordinates to latitude and longitude?

Tags: geojson

I'm receiving this point data from USGS

```
coordinates: Array(3)
0: -100.8913
1: 18.4634
2: 81.41
```

when i try to use [0] and [1] as lat / lng respectivly, they show up in the wrong location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lat and Lon are reversed in geojson. here it is in my example

```
coordinates: Array(3)
0: -100.8913 <- Lon
1: 18.4634 <- Lat
2: 81.41
```